# Scala: generic function taking function with not known arity as argument

Tags: scala, generics

I have some functions like these ones (I don't know the arity, I just know that the return is of type `Future[T]`):

```
def a(a: Int): Future[String] = { Future("a") }
def b(b: Long): Future[Double] = { Future(1.0) }
```

I'd like to write a generic function `WithLoading` that could be used like this:

```
def a(a: Int): Future[String] = WithLoading { Future("a") }
def b(b: Long, c: Int): Future[Double] = WithLoading { Future(1.0) }
```

and would do the same result as:

```
def a(a: Int): Future[String] = { var loading = true; Future("a").map (_ =>  loading = false) }
def b(b: Long): Future[Double] = { var loading = true; Future(1.0).map (_ =>  loading = false) }
```

Is it is possible to do this? And if the answer is yes, could you please give me some advice?

Comment: What is this loading value? You can't call `loading = false` when only starting to execute the future.

Comment: This loading variable is actually defined as a global variable and not inside the function. I forgot to wait the response of the future to pass it to false in the code provided, I edited my answer

Comment: Capturing mutable state and updating it in shared location is a source of trouble. Why not just register a continuation on the future and signal the completion once it's done?

Comment: I know but this is part of a scalajs application so I find it acceptable because it's the same mutable state updated in every files of the application. For the question, this is what I am doing today, but I'm tired of writing these lines for every functions (moreover, I also have to write the future recover part), that's why I'm looking for a generic way of doing it.

Comment: And which function is taking a function with unknown arity as argument?

Comment: withLoading, but as stated by @simpadjo the function doesn't need to know about the arity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `WithLoading` doesn't need to know about arity at all.

```
def withLoading[T](action: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  doSmthWithLoading
  val triggeredAction = action
  val result = triggeredAction.onComplete(r => {
    cleanupSmth
  })
  result
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, I didn't know the syntax " : => ". A little question: why do you have to copy the future with "val triggeredAction = action" ?

Comment: Just to emphasize the moment when the future starts